# Autofill cells based on parent cell

Tags: google-sheets

dI have a spreadsheet that I am using to track a project with multiple milestones, let's say a tree house. The milestones are: a ladder, floor, walls x4, and half a roof x2; the only parts we need are: lumber, nails, bolts, washers, and nuts.

We have our milestone in Col A, material name in B, number we need in C, and number we have in D. Like so:

```
1|Mile   | Mat   |  Need | Have
 |-----------------------------
2|Ladder | Lumber| 10
3|       | Bolt  | 40
4|       | Washer| 40
5|Floor  | Lumber| 30
....
```

Somewhere else on the sheet, I want to have `Lumber` in one cell, and be able to type a value into another, say 19. It would put `10` in the `have` column for the ladder, and `9` for the floor.  If somebody could help start the formula, I can extend as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant ways, but assuming the first Ladder line is A2:D2, and you have a lookup table of stock on hand in F2:G, then in D2:

`=MIN(C2,VLOOKUP(B2,F2:G,2,0))`

then in D3, filled down as far as necessary:

`=IFERROR(MAX(0,MIN(C3,VLOOKUP(B3,F$2:G,2,0)-SUMIF(B$2:B2,B3,C$2:C2))))`

Comment: Yes my stock would be in `e` or `f2`. Let's say `f2:G7`. Would your function calc the value for `d2` to be `g1-d2`?

Comment: D2 would be lowest value out of C2, and the stock on hand corresponding to the item in B2.